# SlidingPaneLayout - close from everywhere

Tags: android, slidingpanelayout

Can I somehow setup the `SlidingPaneLayout` to be closable from everywhere and not only when touching outside of the panel content?

Comment: Users can swipe the pane closed whenever they want. You are also welcome to close it yourself by calling `closePane()` on it. Are you looking for something beyond those? If so, explain in detail what you are expecting.

Comment: I want the user to SWIPE the pane to the closed state, no matter where the user touches it. That's what I meant with everywhere. The user can open it by swiping anywhere on the screen, but to close it, he has to swipe from the edge...

Comment: I doubt that's possible, except by forking `SlidingPaneLayout` and changing how it handles touch events.

Comment: I already though so... It's a little off topic, still you may know it: is it possible to set up the `SlidingPaneLayout` so that the content is not moving when opening the pane? As it's the case when you use the `DrawerLayout`...

Comment: I don't know of a way of doing that. In fact, the answer probably is "use `DrawerLayout`".

Comment: I use it already... I want two sliding views, one left, one right... I'll probably will just make it on my own instead of using a `SlidingPaneLayout` and keep the drawer for the left side and put a layout to the right and move it in manually...

Comment: Note that you can have two drawers, one on each side, with `DrawerLayout`.

Comment: I'll check that, didn't know that... Thanks a lot